# как найти все повторяющиеся значения в контейнере map? c++

Tags: c++, map, повторы

как найти все повторяющиеся значения в контейнере map? c++
вывести только повторяющиеся значения, их ключи и количество повторов

Comment: Пройтись по контейнеру и посчитать. Например, с использованием другого map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите еще один мап

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>>
```

Туда просто кладите значение, а в вектор ключи где они появляются

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {

  std::map<int, int> m{{1, 1}, {2, 9}, {3, 1},
                       {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}
                       };

  std::map<int, std::vector<int>> ret{};

  for(const auto& v : m) {
      ret[v.second].push_back(v.first);
  }

  for(const auto& v : ret) {
      if (v.second.size() > 1) {
          std::cout << v.first << " : ";
          for (const auto& vv : v.second) {
              std::cout << vv << " ";
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
      }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```